# In MySQL, how do you change the value of a column in a table depending on an updated column in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm attempting to create a **trigger** that increases the value of a column **INCOME** in the **Salary** database by **500** each time the value of WorkYear in the Employee table is **increased by one year**. For example, if the workYear is 4 and the salary is 1000, the salary should be 1500 if the workYear is increased by one year, 2000 if the workYear is increased by two years, and so on.

I tried to create such trigger and here is my code :

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger increment AFTER UPDATE  on employee 
for each row 
BEGIN
   IF OLD.workYear <> new.workYear THEN
       update salary
     set income = (income + (new.workYear-old.workYear)*500);
   END IF;
END$$
```

The idea behind this code is that after we update the workYear, the trigger should increase the salary by the difference of years * 500, (new.workYear-old.workYear)*500, but it increases all the rows by the same number, (5500 if we add one year, 27500 if we add two years, etc.) which not what we are looking for .

I am new to MySQL and would appreciate it if someone could assist me with this.

Thanks in advance
FaissalHamdi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL an *AFTER* trigger can affect the entire table, so you must declare the update scope in the form of criteria or a join.

> **[Create Trigger in MySQL](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx)**
> To distinguish between the value of the columns *BEFORE* and *AFTER* the DML has fired, you use the `NEW` and `OLD` modifiers.
>
> > The concept is similar but each RDBMS has a slightly different syntax for this, be careful to search for help specifically on your RDBMS.

In the original query these special table references were used to evaluate the change condition however the scope of the update was not defined.

> Assuming that there is a primary key field called `Id` on this `salary` table.

Also note that if you can, the query should be expressed in the form of a set-based operation, instead of static procedural script, this will be more conformant to other database engines.

So lets try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger increment AFTER UPDATE on employee 
for each row 
BEGIN

   UPDATE salary s
   SET income = (income + (new.workYear-old.workYear)*500)
   WHERE s.Id = OLD.Id

END$$
```

Comment: I think the alias to table with update statement should be given in following way
`UPDATE salary s
SET income = (income + (new.workYear-old.workYear)*500) WHERE s.Id = OLD.Id`

Comment: In single-statement trigger creation query the BEGIN-END block and delimeter reassign are excess.

Comment: thanks @vignesh I got stuck in MS SQL mode... I totally missed the MySQL tag when I first responded, I've updated the post.

Comment: @Akina . . . I strongly disagree.  `BEGIN` and `END` make it very clear what the body of the trigger is.  It also means the trigger is easier to modify.